# How to get the last term from taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy, terms

working on a scholar journal in which publisher add issues to the "issue" taxonomy assigned with articles. i need to display outside the loop a list of posts assigned only with the last issue (recently added).
any help please?

update:
i found a code to get the last term from a taxonomy:

```
$issue = get_terms('issue','orderby=none&order=DESC&number=1');
$current_issue = $issue[0]->slug;
```

But i couldn't find a way to use it to display a list of posts assigned only with that last term. any suggestions please?

Comment: The code above is not very reliable, but then again, if you need a reliable system, you have to write your own as this is not an added feature by default. Anyways, use `WP_Query` with a `tax_query` to query posts from the returned term

Comment: thanks Mr. @PieterGoosen .. but i have another question on the same issue here (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196181/how-to-get-the-term-before-the-last-from-a-custom-taxonomy)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the paramter "number" to 2 in the line :

```
$terms = get_terms( 'issue', 'orderby=id&order=DESC&number=1' );
```

[How to get the term before the last from a custom taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196181/how-to-get-the-term-before-the-last-from-a-custom-taxonomy)