# How to display terms from two taxonomies in one php code?

Tags: php, taxonomy, terms

Two taxonomies were added to posts :

- volume : in which admin enter the number of the journal volume for each post
- issue : where admin enter the number of the issue under which the post is published

& I use this code on a single page (outside the loop) to display a list of journal issues:

```
$args = array( 'hide_empty=0' );
$terms = get_terms( 'issue', 'orderby=id&order=DESC' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $count = count( $terms );
    $i = 0;
    $term_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) . '"> Issue (' . $term->name . ')</a>';
        if ( $count != $i ) {
            $term_list .= ' &middot; ';
        }
        else {
            $term_list .= '</p>';
        }
    }
    echo $term_list;
}
```

The code shows results as e.g. "Issue (i)" where i is the number of issue. I need it to display results like "Issue (N, i)" where N is the volume number (term name) & i is the issue number (term name) both are entered by admin in relevant taxonomies.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your question does not make much sense, is this inside the loop or single post. Also, what exactly are `i` and `N`. Are they terms under the relevant taxonomies, and if they are, are they term names or slugs

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i use this code on a single page not post, i & N are the terms entered by admin in the relevant taxonomies & they are names. waiting for your answer please. regards

Comment: What do you mean by single page. Pages does not have taxonomies. Posts do. As I said, your code does not make sense as you are getting all terms in one taxonomy and trying to couple it to terms in another taxonomy without any means that couple them together. How I read your question is, you need to display `Issue( N, i)` in a single post

Comment: i'm sorry my english isn't so good. i use php code widget in which i entered the code above to display a list of issues/volumes outside the loop where issues & volumes are taxonomies. e.g. issue (5, 7) issue (5, 8) issue (5, 9). 5 is the term name entered in volume taxonomy, 7,8,9 are term names entered in issue taxonomy. the list have links toward the issue archive. i hope its clear now. regards

Comment: How will you know which `volume` to add to which `issue`. Any `issue` can belong to any `volume`, so how will you specifically know volume 5 needs to go with issue 6. ??

Comment: i really have no idea about that. do you suggest to use relations? and how to do that please?

Comment: You are missing some logic somewhere which I cannot help you with. As I said, pages does not have taxonomies by default. The only means I can see this working is displaying `Issue( N, i );` on a single post or inside the loop inside a post, or as a related posts type of functionality. Outside of that, there is no way to create a relationship that you are looking for. The only way to create realtionships is through posts

Comment: ok, i appreciate that. thanks a lot i'll think about it. but if you can help me with another question here (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195921/how-to-get-the-last-term-from-taxonomy) i'll be so gratefull.