# How to get the term before the last from a custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, terms

This code displays the last term added to a taxonomy "issue" which i use to automatically display a link toward my current issue:

```
$args = array( 'hide_empty=0' );
$terms = get_terms( 'issue', 'orderby=id&order=DESC&number=1' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $count = count( $terms );
    $i = 0;
    $term_list = '<p class="arc">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) . '">(' . $term->name . ')</a>';
        if ( $count != $i ) {
            $term_list .= ' </p> ';
        }
        else {
            $term_list .= '';
        }
    }
    echo $term_list;
}
```

I need to display the term before the last to show automatically the link of previous issue of my publications. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the paramter "number" to 2 in the line :

```
$terms = get_terms( 'issue', 'orderby=id&order=DESC&number=1' );
```

You'll get the last 2 terms, so the 2 you want ?

Comment: thanks for your response. no i need just the second term. e.g. issue terms = VOL7, VOL8, VOL9. i need the code to display VOL8. only.